# Why was this answer to the question "Can a player choose to fail a spell's ability check contest?" deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, deleted-answers

The question [Can a player choose to fail a spell's ability check contest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143402/can-a-player-choose-to-fail-a-spells-ability-check-contest) has [a deleted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143402/can-a-player-choose-to-fail-a-spells-ability-check-contest/143415#143415). For users without 10k rep, here's a screenshot of the answer:

[image: "You are assuming (incorrectly) that the Strength check represents some sort if active opposition to the spell’s effect. The contest would still happen even if the creature was unable to actively resist e.g. If they were paralyzed or unconscious. The Strength check simply represents the not-movability (in physics, I’d say inertia but D&D is not a physics engine) of the creature. Strong creatures are harder to move because ... magic. The generally accepted way to read spell effects is that they do what they say - as Jeremy Crawford says "there are no hidden rules". So, it says there is a contest therefore, there is a contest."]

While the post score is very negative, I've noticed that there's no immediate problem that warrants the deletion of this answer. It is an answer, albeit many people do not agree with it - but that is not grounds for deletion.

**Why this answer was deemed worthy of deletion? And if it is not worthy, is it worthy to be undeleted?**

Comment: I think the stated issues are that it isn't back up in the sources.

Comment: Good question, on a glance, the answer does not meet the criteria for deletion and shouldn't have been deleted. Instead, it should have been marked with a not backed by citation label.

Comment: @Akixkisu Marked how?

Comment: @T.J.L. I'm assuming they mean the "citations needed" post notice that moderators can add.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Ah, well... In that case, this question is all on you. Why didn't *you* add one? NautArch and I don't have that power, just delete. ;)

Comment: @T.J.L. hah! Well at that time I didn't have that power (as evidenced by the fact the my delete vote was apparently not binding) ;-)

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange posts on "[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)" and "[Why shouldn't I delete wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293)" and "[Should horribly wrong answers be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120298)". Also [the trusted user privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and [the Stack Overflow help center section on deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)"

Comment: I don't know if RPG.SE has specific policies or guidelines for deleting answers but the following quote from that first link may be important: "[...] These are general guidelines; some communities in the network may uphold more specific reasons to delete posts or not. [...]" I did find the following though: "[When should I vote to undelete an answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8811)"

Comment: More related things: "[If a valid answer is downvoted, what's the motivation not to delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128741)" and "[Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240427)" and the existence of the Peer Pressure badge which is awarded if you "Delete own post with score of -3 or lower"

Answer (score 8):

## It is site practice to delete unsupported answers

Admittedly it's never really documented/discussed on it's own, but mostly in the discussions around fun topics like game recommendations and designer intent requests. Specifically, when the questions type *really* needs supported answers, aren't getting them, and we need to talk about how to moderate them.

But it does also show up in other guidance: [What are the citation expectations of answers on RPG Stack Exchange?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/52137)

> We don't want your opinion; we want your *expertise*. If you do not have experiences you can bring to the table in that particular case, *do not answer the question*. Answers not doing so may be downvoted and/or deleted.

(It talks about experiences as citations because it's from the section on subjective questions, however I see no reason to distinguish the two on this other than what type of support the answer needs to bring.)

#### But haven't we got a post notice for this?

Yes, there's a post notice for needing citations, but post notices are a poor tool for moderating content. They are fixed wordings and only available to a very small subset of users. Comments are better at pointing out problems because they are customizable (by default you write out each one) and availible to many users. The post notice does also not exclude deletion, but explicitly warns about it:

> **Want to improve this post?** Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

Let me try to explain why that post notice get used at all, if those answers should get deleted. Firstly, deletion might not be the correct thing. If the answer is probably salvageable, users should get a chance to edit it, or comment for the poster to do so. Also, diamond mod deletions are instant, and harder to revert (can't be undeleted by non-diamonds). There's also an important learning and healthiness aspect to community doing moderation and evaluations, so we often try to not immediately delete (nor close, etc.) borderline cases.

So, we prefer to let the low quality review process do its thing. We might flag the post (if it wasn't already), add a comment with out concern (again, if it's not already covered), and add the post notice for increased visibility of it (if we remember to/think it's worthwhile). Expecting the post notice to be used beyond this is putting an aspect of site moderation too much onto the diamond mods, I hope you want us to put our efforts into more useful things.

## So for the specific answer

Without support being added to it, I don't see it having any value. And it being deleted does not prevent the poster (nor 10ks I believe) from editing it. The user could then vote to undelete and/or flag for undeletion (if diamond deleted, as this one retroactively is, the flag is necessary). No such efforts have been made on this answer. I don't personally see the reason to undelete it, but I'd be happy for someone to change my view on the quality of an answer at a score of -6.

Answer (score 1):

### The SE guidelines point towards that answer having been deleted *incorrectly*

I suggest reading the following:

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)
- [Why shouldn't I delete wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293)
- [If a valid answer is downvoted, what's the motivation not to delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128741)
- [Why is an answer that is so bad it is shown faded out kept around? Why not delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240427)
  The Stack Overflow Help Center section on [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

All of these promote *not* deleting answers solely because they have downvotes and promote deleting answers when they are not actually honest attempts at answers. To quote those links:

> For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.

> A wrong answer, downvoted, also conveys information. It tells you, the visitor: don't do this. This answer is wrong, and if you are lucky the comments tell you why it is wrong.

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answersasking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

---

#### As far as I can find, RPG.SE does not have guidelines or policies that supercede the general Stack guidelines.

We can compare RPG.SE to something like Skeptics where (according the their [Meta welcome](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1505)):

> [...] Questions must be about a notable claim [...]
>
> [...] Answers need references [...]

RPG.SE does *not* have similar requirements that I have found. We *do* have the following question:

- [When should I vote to undelete an answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8811)

And the answer there simply states:

> [...] vote to undelete when you don’t think it should be deleted. [...]

I don't think this is any sort of fundamental change to deletion and undeletion across the site, but I thought that answer was worth mentioning.

---

### The answer in question should be undeleted

The answer in question is not spam or anything similar. It is an honest attempt at an answer to the question. As such, it has no reason to be deleted. For me, improper deletion is one of the strongest reasons to undelete something. Keeping it deleted would promote similar deletions which we, as far as I can find, do not want.

That said, the post's own author may still choose to keep the answer deleted. If they do, I personally believe that that decision should be respected. But RPG.SE policies on undeleting posts deleted by their authors should be left to a different Meta entirely.

I personally cannot say *why* this answer was deleted, because I did not vote to delete it. It was likely due to the lack of citations, and posts I linked to earlier say that bad answers that are still honest attempts at answers should *not* be deleted. To me, the general guidelines lead to the conclusion that the post in question was incorrectly deleted and for me an incorrect deletion should be undone.

---

#### The general SE guidelines have *some* pushback

The previously linked posts are all in support of not deleting downvoted or flatly incorrect posts; meanwhile the following post also exists:

- [Should horribly wrong answers be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120298)

And an answer there states:

> Yes, absolutely. That's why high rep users can vote to delete. That is also why there is a peer pressure badge, to encourage users to delete their own downvoted content.
>
> We want to identify harmful answers, but we do not necessarily want them to stick around. Even though their scores are negative, even though the content might be grayed out, people can still see them, ignore the warnings (or not even understand them) and use the content. [...]

So not *everyone* agrees whether flatly incorrect answers are unhelpful or whether they should be deleted but the SE general guidelines state that they should not be deleted.

Perhaps worth mentioning, the Peer Pressure badge exists and is awarded when you:

> Delete own post with score of -3 or lower

This isn't the same situation, since it's about the author deleting their own post but it could be construed as SE incentivizing deleting posts solely because they have downvotes, which would go against the general guideline. However, this badge also has [quite a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Peer+pressure+%5Bbadges%5D+closed%3A0) Meta posts about it including

- [Why are there badges that promote poor answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341802)
- [Badges should reward positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107628)
- [Please get rid of the peer pressure badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231270)

Comment: The post notice you recommend us adding does say that answers may be deleted: "Want to improve this post? Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted."

Comment: @Someone I still think the post notice should have happened and do not see anything in the general guidelines or RPG.SE posts and guidelines saying they *will* be deleted. That something may be deleted doesn't mean it should be. I can question the post notice if you'd like since I don't think it should say that given what the general guidelines and other MSE posts say. Actually, I'll just remove the post notice thing since the general guidelines and other linked posts cover this situation plenty for me

Comment: I've been told not to flag for needing citation, so the process is up to the community for downvoting and deletion if answers are unsupported.

Comment: @NautArch I'm part of the community and believe that "Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted" and "A wrong answer, downvoted, also conveys information. It tells you, the visitor: don't do this" provide enough reason to let the answer remain

Comment: The problem wasn't the answer being wrong, it was lack of support. And those can be deleted as per the notice.

Comment: If you can address why this was supported or if we shouldnt be following through with what we earn about in post notiices for unsupported, that'd help.